# http proxy middleware changes method From 'POST' to 'GET' on redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-proxy

I'm using `http-proxy-middleware` in my recat app  as follows

```
module.exports = function (app) {
       app.use(
            "/api",
           createProxyMiddleware(filter, {
           target: "https://example.com/",
           secure: false,
           changeOrigin: false,
           logLevel: "debug",
           followRedirects: true,
           onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {},
           onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
               const exchange = `[${req.method}] [${proxyRes.statusCode}] ${req.path} -> 
             ${proxyRes.req.protocol}//${proxyRes.req.host}${proxyRes.req.path}`;
    console.log(exchange);
  },
           onError: (err, req, res, target) => {
                   console.log(err);
          },
      })
   );
 };
```

I set followRedirects = true otherwise I get a 301 and then a `405 Method not allowed`
now I get just the 405 I can see that the request is changed to a 'GET' request which is rejected by the server

this is my request

```
axios({
     method: "POST",
     data: data,
     url: url,
  }).then(r =>{
        ...
  })
```